# How to the calculate the value of capacitor placed in series with transformer to avoid flux walking in a buck converter?

Tags: capacitor, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

The dc value of current in primary increases(in -ve direction) as time passes, so I need a capacitor in series with transformer, but don't know what value capacitor should I use.
[image]

filter capacitor = 1 mF

filter inductor = 50 uH

switching frequency = square wave inverter's frequency = 50kHz

Comment: You need to show us a schematic diagram, with component values, in order to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I've added the schematic,

Comment: What *is* this thing? Why is there an inverter immediately after the rectifier?

Comment: purpose of the inverter is to increase the frequency of the AC voltage from 50 Hz to 50KHz,, because at higher frequencies the size of required transformer decreases,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to read up on [what constitutes a good schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/105136/11683). At a minimum *every* component should have a reference designator and a value, so we can talk about them meaningfully.

Just as a rough cut, I see that you have a 30A load and a 7:1 transformer, which suggests that the primary current is going to be a little over 4A. Assuming you want to pass that current with minimum loss, let's assume an AC impedance of about 1 Ω, which, at 50 kHz, implies a capacitance on the order of 3 µF. That's a lot of current (and voltage) for one capacitor, but as long as this is a theoretical/simulation exercise, it shouldn't matter.

There are some caveats, however. If the capacitor should happen to resonate with the primary of the transformer at the switching frequency, the current and voltage will rise dramatically, so check for this.

As a side note, I would point out that your drive circuit for the H-bridge isn't going to work in the real world. The high-side N-channel MOSFETs can't be driven with the same signals that are used for the low-side devices. Remember, the gate-to-source voltage on any MOSFET can't ever exceed a certain value, usually around ±20V.

Comment: All I wanted was "the impedance of the capacitor should be very less than the impedance seen at the primary of the transformer and it should not resonate with the primary".
As far as the schematic is concerned, since it is just for the purpose of the simulation and all symbols are standard(except for the gate driver's, that are connected to the gates of the mosfets and take care of that high side signals problem you pointed out to) so I didn't think it was necessary to put model name below every component.

Comment: and I didn't mention the values(before I posted the schematic) because I just wanted to know how to calculate the value of cap and not what value cap should I use for this specific circuit. Anyways, thanks for your answer.