# Need help to understand this circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm trying to understand this circuit, it's been a long time since I messed with electronics.

I even managed to understand some things, for example:
The first ICL7660 circuit will be used as a source to create a -9V signal.

The AD620 should pre-amplify the muscle signal.

The Capacitor and resistor in series at the output of the AD620 I did not understand.

The block with the two diodes from what I understand are rectifying the signal, but I don't understand why they are connecting between one amplifier and the other.

The RC filter on the top right is for filtering high frequencies.

**Could you help me understand the blocks of the op amp?**

I got to assemble this circuit but it didn't work, it has a lot of noise. Shouldn't it have a 200Hz filter?

[image: EMG Circuit]

Project source:
https://stoppi-homemade-physics.de/emg/

Comment: This "schematic" is a weird cross between a proper schematic and some sort of illustration. I've never seen one like it before, maybe I will have to add it to the [list](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/105136/2028)!

Comment: EMG is a very noisy signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a diff amplifier with gain around 200 followed by a 1st order 100 Hz highpass filter. The two OpAmps with all these 150 k ohm resistors and diodes remove the sign of the AC signal (|x|) and the OpAmp with the 1 uF capacitor integrates it into an effective DC value. The last OpAmp stage is just a linear DC amplifier. The total gain is between 0 and 5000. I miss a 10 uF capacitor between +9 V and GND as companion for the other one.

Comment: Where does the output of the rectifier get filtered?  It doesn't look like it goes anywhere

Comment: Oh, I see the "A" label now.