Raspberry Pi Pico W Project - Temperature Sensor not working when battery powered
I'm brand new to microcontrollers so I suspect this is a simple misunderstanding of how circuits work. I have a project that reads temperature information from a DHT11 sensor and displays it on an OLED screen as well as sends the information to a webpage.
When I switch the project to be powered by 2 AA batteries and change the OLED screen to get power from VSYS instead of the VBUS on the Pico W, my temperature and humidity readings read: "inf". I suspect I've made a mistake wiring my components or I need a greater power supply than 3V.
USB Powered Diagram

Battery Powered Diagram

In case it isn't clear, the resistor that connects my push-button to the ground rail is 10k ohms. If anyone could guide me in the right direction to getting this resolved I would really appreciate it :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you add a schematic instead of a breadboard image? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105136/whats-a-schematic-compared-to-other-diagrams

Your lack of a schematic makes it hard to tell exactly what's going on, but if you're using the bare DHT-11 module as shown in the cartoon image, a pullup resistor, such as 4k7Ω, on the data line is required.

Welcome! Those Fritzing diagrams sure are pretty. However, they are not well received here because they tend to become very difficult to parse and decode for troubleshooting. Consider using the built in schematic tool (click the schematic symbols icon when making/editing the question) and look through this site's guidelines on schematic creation. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics -Good luck!

Output of inf suggests "Infinity" (a value printed from a floating point variable)... if possible, please dig into the issue further, as this doesn't provide much insight - either in the firmware, or by using an oscilloscope or logic analyzer.

The 2 AA batteries are not sufficient for your whole setup. Either use 3 AA batteries or get a power bank. Here you will find 6 ways to power up a Raspberry PI Pico. You can choose a suitable way from these.
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/power-raspberry-pi-pico-6-different-ways/
You can also check this setup. It's a temperature and humidity control unit using Raspberry Pi Pico. This one has some common components with your setup. So, you will get a better idea.
https://www.pcbway.com/blog/16/Temperature_Humidity_Control_Unit_Using_a_Raspberry_Pi_Pico_66fdee4a.html
